# NSDateFormatter crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format a date using a NSDateFormatter but my app is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here's the code:

```
DateInputTableViewCell *cell0 = (DateInputTableViewCell *)[paramTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
DateInputTableViewCell *cell1 = (DateInputTableViewCell *)[paramTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];

NSString *fromDate = [[Helpers defaultFormatter] stringFromDate:cell0.dateValue];
NSString *toDate = [[Helpers defaultFormatter] stringFromDate:cell1.dateValue];
```

The code above I'm getting the date from two custom UITableViewCell that I have. The values are not null (I've tested). But when I try to use my defaultFormatter method from my Helpers class, the app crashes. Below is the code:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)defaultFormatter{
    defaultFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"];
    [defaultFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Sao_Paulo"]];
    [defaultFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"];
    [defaultFormatter setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];
    return defaultFormatter;
}
```

The custom UITableViewCell's NSDateFormatter is defined like this:

```
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
self.dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
```

I saw some similar questions here but couldn't fix this problem!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Including a crash log would probably help...

Comment: Where is your `return` statement in `defaultFormatter` method? You should return the `defaultFormatter` after setting those values.

Comment: I forgot to include the return statement! Code edited!

Comment: I included an image with the crash log.

Answer (score 1):

Your `defaultFormatter` method isn’t returning anything, so you get a garbage value to which you try to send the `stringFromDate:` message which leads to a crash. The compiler should warn you about this, so always fix your compiler warnings!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, `return` statement is missing in your `defaultFormatter` method. You should return the `defaultFormatter` after setting the values.

It should be like this,

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)defaultFormatter{
    defaultFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"];
    [defaultFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Sao_Paulo"]];
    [defaultFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"];
    [defaultFormatter setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];
    return defaultFormatter;
}
```

Comment: `defaultFormatter` is declared is an `@property` in your code?

Comment: No, it's a static as `static NSDateFormatter *defaultFormatter;`

Comment: Why dont you try to use a different name for `defaultFormatter` static param since the method also has the same name.

Comment: And what if you declare it as normal @property in your Helper class? Is it still crashing?

Comment: It's not possible to declare as @property because I have class method ( `+(NSDateFormatter *)defaultFormatter` ). I already use this method in other classes in my app. Only this specific class is crashing...